# MongoDB old Databases & collections not accessible - Mongod.exe and Mongo.exe running

Tags: r, mongodb, database

I'm a MongoDB beginner.

I'm working on Intellijidea IDE to develop JAVA program in the aim to execute data mining processes on social media like Twitter and Facebook, based on Twitter4j and Facebook4j.

I use MongoDB to store database collections for test and evaluation purposes. I have saved several MongoDB databases, which were all accessible until a few days, in a folder as E:/data/db. So, all my previous databases are accessible in E:/data/db and I can easily control the structure of the databases collections through a terminal command in windows shell (show dbs(), show collections(), db stats()).

Last week, I launched a new data mining database collection, with several collections, and probably made a mistake in the localization of the database on my computer, where I put the new database in E:/data/db/newdatabase.

The problem is that I need to get the data mining process running while I would like to analyze the old databases collections through the R software.

Right now, I'm not able to access to the old MongoDB databases on Windows terminal command, as I can see only that there is some bytes, but no structured collections etc… When I'm trying to call the collections and the databases from R with rmongodb package, I'm not able to see the previous collections.

Might I be able to restore the old databases collections with Mongo restore or something like that ? What Kind of mistake could I have done to keep these old databases collections not accessible while there were a few days ago ?

Comment: Add the name as Name of your acc. There is no thanks or such at Stackoverflow. See this post why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB is not intended to be manipulated at the filesystem level.

Instead, you should be using mongoexport and mongoimport to transfer individual databases.

Comment: I used the both methods to copy/paste the old databases I have built, and it seems working well. The methods are clearly described on MongoDB user manual and MongoDB Website. Very instructive.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you still have your collections data in your E:\data\db directory, named with your collection name

```
yourCollection.0
yourCollection.1
yourCollection.ns
```

Try by copy your newdatabase and db folder in a new folder (like E:\backup) then try to start two mongo instance :

```
mongod --dbpath=E:\backup\db --port 27001
mongod --dbpath=E:\backup\newdatabase --port 27002
```

try to connect to each dabase and check if eveything is ok (no data corruption, ...)

```
mongo --port 27001
mongo --port 27002
```

If it's ok, then, as jmkgreen explain, export your database, and import it in your previous database.

Comment: It seems working well, using mongo export & mongo import methods suggested by jmkgreen & found on MongoDB user manual. I have just start a new mongod.exe and mongo.exe instances on a specific port (27003), while my data mining instance working, connected to a database collection (use old_database), and found some positive data with db.stats() command. I will test through R and rmongod if I can check the objects integrity inside each collections. I will write you back ASAP.

Comment: Excellent, working also on R too. I can now analyze databases collections separately with rmongod package on R with connecting to the secondary MongoDB instances, while the first one is working for data collection on social media websites. A good step forward !